# Troubles with putty to connect to VM CentOS 7 (Vagrant / Virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox, putty, centos-7, vagrant

I've created a VM CentOS7 using Vagrant (2.2.3) and Virtual Box (5.2.24), on Windows 10 in this way (following these instructions ... https://blog.centos.org/2019/02/updated-centos-vagrant-images-available-v1901-01/)

```
vagrant init centos/7
vagrant up
```

And all works fine

Then I've installed the Guest Addition (rif. https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest), in this way

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

And my final `Vagrantfile` is the follow

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "4096"
     vb.name = "Test"
   end
end
```

The `vagrant up` execution works fine

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' version '1901.01' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
[default] GuestAdditions 5.2.24 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => D:/Cesare/Personale/VagrantCentOS7/TestNew
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

The VM starts and `vagrant ssh` works fine, but when I try to connect via Putty (SSH on port 22), using the IP address (192.168.33.10) I obtain the following error

[image]

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a high enough reputation to comment, but I can post an answer.

Take a look at the **/var/log/messages** file when you connect via `vagrant ssh`.  I suspect that the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file has **PermitRootLogin** set to **without-password** or some other similar setting.  If you want to connect as root with a password change it to **PermitRootLogin yes**.

Comment: You're right! I've edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file with `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and changed `#PasswordAuthentication yes
` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`(uncommented the line ...). Then I've restarted sshd service with the command  `sudo systemctl restart sshd`  and now all works fine when I connect my VM CentOS 7 from Putty.